# Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: "com.mopub.mobileads.VungleInterstitial"

Tags: android, android-studio, mopub, vungle-ads

In Mopub admob interstitial & facebook interstitial works fine but for vungle am getting debug message like this

Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: "com.mopub.mobileads.VungleInterstitial".

[image]

```
 D/MoPub: Loading custom event interstitial adapter.
 D/MoPub: Attempting to invoke custom event: "com.mopub.mobileads.VungleInterstitial"
 D/MoPub: Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: "com.mopub.mobileads.VungleInterstitial".
 V/MoPub: MoPubErrorCode: Unable to find Native Network or Custom Event adapter.
 D/MoPub: Loading failover url:
```

Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mopubads"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }   
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'   
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.15.0'
    compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'
    compile files('libs/dagger-2.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-4.0.3.jar')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

proguard

```
-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}
-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.** { public *; }
-keep public class com.mopub.**
-keep class com.mopub.mobileads.** {*;}


-dontwarn com.vungle.**
-keep class com.vungle.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.*
```

Comment: Are you using AndroidStudio?

Comment: yes am using AndroidStudio IDE

Comment: Post ur app gradle file

Comment: folder structure is right , thats not the problem. please see my log

Comment: Check your gradle file in that u have ,compile project(':Your lib') line ?

Comment: i have that line compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

Comment: remove that line and try to add the module dependency from the module setting->app-> dependency . This issue causes while the correct path is not getting to the application

Comment: One more thing how to add the mopub-android-sdk modue

Comment: i hope path is right because am getting admob interstitial & facebook interstitial

Comment: @Nithinlal  this line of code adds the mopub-android-sdk modue compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.9.0@aar') { transitive = true }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130284/discussion-between-nithinlal-and-sarath).